# Selector for locating the second element not within the same parent

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Given the following HTML:

```
<div>
    <span class="my-class">One</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="my-class">Two</span>
</div>
```

Can I use a CSS Selector using the class attribute `my-class` to locate only the second span
(`<span class="my-class">Two</span>`)? Note that the `<span>`s are in different `<div>`s.

I've tried `.my-class:nth-child(2)` and `.my-class:nth-of-type(2)`, which do not work. Also if possible, I would like to avoid using XPaths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `:nth-child` to target the second `div` and then find the class you want inside it:

```css
div:nth-child(2) .my-class{
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="my-class">One</span>
</div>
<div>
    <span class="my-class">Two</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `:nth-child` and `:nth-of-type` pseudo-class selectors you are targeting siblings. In other words, the elements must have the same parent.

`.my-class:nth-child(2)` and `.my-class:nth-of-type(2)` will not work as expected because you are targeting the second element inside the `div` container, which doesn't exist.

Since both divs are siblings (children of `body`), consider targeting the second `div`:

```
div:nth-child(2) > .my-class
```

Answer (score -1):

An addition to @koala_dev 's answer, if you want to avoid using XPaths, you can give id attribute to each span to catch them. If you are using a script language, you can print your `<span>`'s by using a loop and you can set id's of each  to loop variable. For example

```css
#span-2{
  background:red;
  }
```

```html
<div>
       <span class="my-class" id="span-1">One</span>
    </div>
    <div>
       <span class="my-class" id="span-2">Two</span>
    </div>
```